# Injecting dynamic content into an Orchard page body

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

Is it possible to inject dynamic content into an Orchard page body? I would like to inject the id of the current logged in user into links.

My initial thought was to use token replacement, so entering `<a href="http://www.someurl.com?id=[memberid]"></a>` would replace [memberid] with the logged in user id at runtime. Is there a way I can intercept the response and run some custom code before it is sent back to the client?

[This question](https://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/459020) is the same, however the answer is very specific to their issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tokens might be the proper way to go, however I haven't digged into that yet. But if you want to change the response you can use response filters.

I used it to minify resulting HTML in this module https://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.JadeX.HtmlMarkupMinifier

Here's the code that should do the trick or at least give you an idea.

```
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Orchard;
using Orchard.Mvc.Filters;
using Orchard.UI.Admin;

public class TokenReplacementFilter : FilterProvider, IActionFilter
{
    private readonly WorkContext _workContext;

    public TokenReplacementFilter(IWorkContextAccessor workContextAccessor)
    {
        _workContext = workContextAccessor.GetContext();
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) {
        // Only apply the token replacement if logged in and not in the Orchard admin area
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Filter == null || _workContext.CurrentUser == null || AdminFilter.IsApplied(filterContext.RequestContext))
            return;

        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Filter = new TokenReplacementStream(filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Filter, filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Output.Encoding, _workContext);
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
    }
}

internal class TokenReplacementStream : MemoryStream
{
    private readonly Stream _stream;
    private readonly Encoding _encoding;
    private string _html;
    private readonly WorkContext _workContext;

    public TokenReplacementStream(Stream filter, Encoding encoding, WorkContext workContext)
    {
        _stream = filter;
        _encoding = encoding;
        _workContext = workContext;
    }

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        _html += _encoding.GetString(buffer);
    }

    public override void Flush()
    {
        if (_html != null) {
            _html = _html.Replace("[memberid]", _workContext.CurrentUser.Id.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
            _stream.Write(_encoding.GetBytes(_html), 0, _encoding.GetByteCount(_html));   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, just given this a go but I'm getting a HttpException with the unhelpful message of 'Filtering is not allowed.' with the error code -2147467259. It does still hit the code in the Flush method in the filter however.

Comment: Dang, sorry to hear that. I've added one null check to OnActionExecuting, can you please try it with that? Also if you run in debug mode, try disabling it if it helps.

Comment: The null check did the trick thanks. I also had to not apply the filter if on the admin site as that was replacing my tokens! There was a compile error due to the WorkContext not being accessible in 1 area, I've fixed this and made a few naming changes to better fit my project. I've put in an edit but it says it needs to be 'peer reviewed', once this is done I'll mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: The edit has been rejected for some reason, it says 'This edit is incorrect or an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post.'. However I've come across a problem, it errors when logging out of the site, just looking into it now.

Comment: The error was to do with some other code and was irrelevant to this. I've made a few improvements to the code to eliminate some bugs I came across but as noted above it keeps getting rejected when I try to edit it. I don't want to post the answer myself and accept that as you deserve the credit. I could post it in an answer which will allow you to copy and paste it then I can delete the answer, what do you think?

Comment: I've posted an answer with the code in and the changes explained. Feel free to take the code and I will accept your answer and delete mine

Comment: Done. I've also took liberty of changing your Admin checking to be filter based rather than theme based as theme name may change in the future.

Comment: Brilliant! Wasn't aware of this AdminFilter. Many thanks for all your help.